# Run a task once at a time in the ignite cluster

Tags: ignite

I have a task to run continuously on one node in the ignite cluster. When the task completes or fails, it should be started again on the oldest node. How can I do this?

```
class MyTask {

    @PostConstruct()
    public void start() {
        ignite.executorService(ignite.cluster().forOldest())
                .submit(() -> myTask());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start singleton Ignite Service(https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/service-grid) with a filter for the oldest node. It will guarantee failover safety.

Inside service's "execute" method, you can have while loop with starting the task. Using that, you can handle task completing and failing and restart it again.